# React validation issue for render value

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I'm using react Yup validation and I have a problem(Edit form) with the validation when editing something. Even though the fields are filled the validator behaves like they are empty. I've logged the state and the values appear also there..Same code working fine without `value={contactPersonName || ""}` parameter... Refer the attached image

```html
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import MaintanaceRequestService from "../../service/tenant/MaintanaceRequestService";
import axios from "axios";
import { CheckSquare } from "react-feather";
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
  CardBody,
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  Col,
} from "reactstrap";

const formValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  contactPersonName: Yup.string().nullable().required("Required"),
  priority: Yup.number().required("Required"),
  contactPersonEmail: Yup.string()
    .email("Invalid email address")
    .required("Required"),
});

class MaintananceUpdate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    successAlert: true,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let mess = "";
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/tenant/maint/preEdit/", {
        maintId: "1144",
      })

      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.maintReq);
        mess = response.data.maintReq;

        this.setState({
          updatable: true,
          contactPersonName: mess.contactPersonName,
          contactPersonEmail: mess.contactPersonEmail,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { contactPersonName, contactPersonEmail } = this.state;

    return (
      <Card>
        <CardHeader>
          <CardTitle>Maintanance Request</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              contactPersonEmail: "",
              contactPersonName: "",
            }}
            validationSchema={formValidation}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              values.issueType = values.issueType.value;

              console.log(values.priority);
              setTimeout(() => {
                MaintanaceRequestService.createRequest(values).then(
                  (response) =>
                    this.setState({
                      description: response.data.description,
                    })
                );
                console.log(values);

                this.successMessgae("successAlert", true);
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 1000);
            }}
          >
            {(props) => {
              const { handleSubmit, setFieldValue, handleBlur } = props;
              return (
                <Form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label htmlFor="contactPersonName">Person Name</label>
                    <Field
                      className="form-control"
                      name="contactPersonName"
                      placeholder="Doe"
                      type="text"
                      value={contactPersonName || ""}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        this.setState({ contactPersonName: e.target.value })
                      }
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="contactPersonName"
                      component="div"
                      className="field-error text-danger"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <label htmlFor="contactPersonEmail">Email</label>
                    <Field
                      className="form-control"
                      name="contactPersonEmail"
                      placeholder="jane@acme.com"
                      type="email"
                      value={contactPersonEmail || ""}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        this.setState({ contactPersonEmail: e.target.value })
                      }
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                    />

                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="contactPersonEmail"
                      component="div"
                      className="field-error text-danger"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup row>
                    <Col md={{ size: 8, offset: 4 }}>
                      <Button.Ripple
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        className="mr-1 mb-1"
                      >
                        <CheckSquare size={14} />
                        <span className="align-middle ml-25">Submit</span>
                      </Button.Ripple>
                    </Col>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Form>
              );
            }}
          </Formik>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
export default MaintananceUpdate;
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWQg1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding enableReinitialize to formik solved my issue

```html
<Formik
          enableReinitialize
          ..
          render={
            ({
              ..
            }) => ( 
             //form uses initialValues
          )} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using your own `handleChange`. So once you are done doing your stuff in your handleChange, call formik's `handleChange`. Unless you call formik's handleChange, formik wouldn't be aware of changes on your `Field`

```js
...
const { handleSubmit, setFieldValue, handleBlur, handleChange } = props; // <----------- destructure formik's handleChange
return (
<Form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
    <FormGroup>
        <label htmlFor="contactPersonName">Person Name</label>
        <Field
            className="form-control"
            name="contactPersonName"
            placeholder="Doe"
            type="text"
            value={contactPersonName || ""}
            onChange={(e) =>
            {
                this.setState({ contactPersonName: e.target.value })
                handleChange(e) // <----------- call formik's handleChange
            }
            }
            onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
```

Comment: I have tried with formik handlechange but it didnt work, facing same issue